# Access to the path is denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-6

I am currently creating a folder and writing a file to the folder that need to be create on a file server that we have. When i do a localhost test, it work perfectly but when i access the website from outside the localhost and from another pc. It said that

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'My File Server
>   URL' is denied
>
> ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider
>   granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request
>   identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically
>   {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6) that is used if
>   the application is not impersonating. If the application is
>   impersonating via , the identity will be
>   the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated
>   request user.
>
> To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in Explorer,
>   choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add" to add
>   the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account, and
>   check the boxes for the desired access.

But the thing is that i have already set the identity impersonate="true" in the web.config and it still didn't work. My web server is running on Winder Server 2003 and IIS 6

Any advice and help will be deeply appreciated

Thanks
Brandon

Comment: reboot, often IIS stops getting access to directories out of the blue and rebooting the machine is the only option, give it a shot

Comment: i try but i can't can't. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Guys i manage to find the solution to it 
If u are creating a folder, using this code before file or folder creation

```
WindowsImpersonationContext ctx = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(IntPtr.Zero);
// Insert the create code here
ctx.Undo();
```

Well i do not know if this is the best solution. if anyone know the downside or implication of this code please share and comment.

no harm knowing more

Answer (score 4):

You need to grant `write`, `modify` permission to the `Users` group for that `file/folder`.

Comment: This fixed it. The line was an OpenRead - so why these permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Check your IIS Authentication setting and make sure that Anonymous authentication is enabled.